# Python range and for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I was toying around with Python and I ran the following:

```
for i,j in (range(-1, 2, 2),range(-1, 2, 2)):
    print(i,j)
```

I expected this to print

```
>> -1, -1
>> 1, 1
```

However what came out was

```
>> -1, 1
>> -1, 1
```

(1) Why is this the output and what is going on behind the scenes

(2) If I wanted to get all combinations of -1 and 1 (which are(-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1), and (1,1)) I know that I can use a nested for loop

```
for i in range(-1,2,2):
    for j in range(-1,2,2):
        print(i,j)
```

However is there a way to do this in one line with one for loop call (what I was trying to do with the original code)?

Comment: You have two question here, can you please edit it down to one? Thanks

Comment: Sorry about the two questions in what was supposed to be one question. I thought they were so related that they could be thought of as parts of a question. Someone already answered the question so I won't change it now but I will keep that in mind for the future! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, in the first iteration loop it takes `range(-1, 2, 2)` which expands to `[-1, 1]` and then assigns `i=-1` and `j=1`. Similarly in the second cycle it does the same for the second `range(-1, 2, 2)`. You're lucky that you have two elements in that range. Otherwise it would raise error, e.g., `range(-1, 4, 2)` would raise error as it has 3 elements. You need to use i, j, k for that loop.

For your second question use `itertools.product`.

```
for i in product(range(-1, 2, 2), range(-1, 2, 2)): 
    print(i)
    #(-1, -1)
    #(-1, 1)
    #(1, -1)
    #(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

First question : 
You are iterating over i and j over a tuple  (range(-1, 2, 2), range(-1, 2, 2)).
try this code and you'll understand.

```
>>> for i in (range(-1, 2, 2),range(-1, 2, 3)):
...     print(i)
... 
range(-1, 2, 2)
range(-1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think range(-1, 2, 2) is (-1, 1), then

```py
for i, j in (range(-1, 2, 2), range(-1, 2, 2)):
```

is similar

```py
for i, j in ((-1, 1), (-1, 1)):
```

You should do it like this

```py
for i, j in zip(range(-1, 2, 2), range(-1, 2, 2)):
    print(i, j)
```

To all combinations of -1 and 1, use this is more flexiable

```py
for i in range(-1,2,2):
    for j in range(-1,2,2):
        print(i,j)
```

or this

```py
from itertools import product

for i, j in product(range(-1, 2, 2), range(-1, 2, 2)):
```